# How to solve Linux 64k Connection problem

Tags: tcp, connection

I know this is a very old question. Troubled me for 2 days.
I am trying to tune the centos for more than 64K connection by using a Nodejs program listening to port 8000 with one IP, to prove the max connection number of a single IP and single port is more than 64k.

And then when I try to create connection from another VM with different IP, the number of connections goes to 50k+ but can never pass 64k.

I tried to listen to 2 ports with the same software&hardware setup. The number can pass 64K easily.

Don't know what else I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And then when I try to create connection from another VM with different IP, the number of connections goes to 50k+ but can never pass 64k.

You're probably running out of source ports on that machine. Use two VMs to generate the load.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I finally figured it out. I missed some of the tuning option for the kernel memory. Thanks